# Add Text Label and Button to dynamic tableview cell programmatically with Swift

Tags: swift, button, dynamic, tableview, cell

I have a dynamic tableview and a prototype cell which displays an array. My questions is how would I add a button which displays different names on each cell to the Left side of the cell and then a label to the right side displaying the array info. Thanks! :D

So imagine this is the cell below:

Left side:Button(array info)  <------------------->       Right side:TextLabel(array info)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement like this

```
let titleArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return no.of cell do you want
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellHeight = tableView(self.tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section))
    var cell = CustomCell(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, cellHeight), title: titleArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.cellLabel.text = //labelText
    cell.cellButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellButton: UIButton!
    var cellLabel: UILabel!

    init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cellLabel= UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.frame.width - 100, 10, 100.0, 40))
        cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cellLabel.font = //set font here

        cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 30))
        cellButton.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        addSubview(cellLabel)
        addSubview(cellButton)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for your question, please follow the below steps

```
var data = ["iPad", "iPhone", "iWatch", "iPod", "iMac"]
var buttonData = ["US","China","London","Canada","Japan"];


//UITableViewDataSource Methods

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
 {
    return 80
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
 {
    return data.count
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(280.0, 14.0, 100.0, 30.0))
    label.text = data[indexPath.row]
    label.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.addSubview(label)


    let btn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    btn.setTitle(buttonData[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 80, 40)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.addSubview(btn)

    return cell
 }

 //Button Action is
 func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton!)
 {
    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    println("button is Pressed")
    println("Clicked Button Row is",buttonRow)
 }
```

Comment: It says buttonWithType is unavailable, use object construction UIButton(type:)... Any suggestions?

Comment: So, how do I have the labels and buttons conform to different size screens?

Comment: when the user will scroll, it will add the label and the button again and again and again ..

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad did you get any solution for this?