# Error while initialisation of TableViewCell with Buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2, custom-cell

I have read the following articles:

1. [creating custom tableview cells in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift)
2. ['required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewCell'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081287/required-initializer-initcoder-must-be-provided-by-subclass-of-uitablevi)
3. [Custom UITableViewCell from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541786/custom-uitableviewcell-from-nib-in-swift)

However, none of them have solved my problem.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I want to dynamically create buttons in a tableview cell like as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053398/add-text-label-and-button-to-dynamic-tableview-cell-programmatically-with-swift). So that I can create as many buttons I want to in a tableview cell.

**The problem:**

However, I keep getting the error `fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented`.

**What I have done so far:**

In my tableview cell class I have the following code:

```
var cellButton: UIButton!

init(title: String) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cellButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 30))
    cellButton.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    addSubview(cellButton)

}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
```

In my tableview class I have written the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = OfficeConnectUserTableViewCell(title: "hello")
    return cell
}
```

Any suggestions to get rid of the error and dynamically create the button inside the cell programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class

Comment: @El Captain I tried removing override func awakeFromNib() as that post suggested. However, the error still remains.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel Hm... It seems to me that you guys are seeing something that I am failing to see. If someone could please explain how the post answers my question, that would be awesome.